# Throwing an exception on a remoting server not defined in the client causes an "Unable to find assembly" exception

Tags: c#, remoting

I have some client code calling a method via remoting using the

```
myProxy = (IProxy)Activator.GetObject(
                    typeof(IProxy),
                    "tcp://" + address + ":" + theControllerPort + "/Proxy");
```

IProxy is defined as

```
    public interface IProxy  {
        void DoStuff();
    }
```

Proxy is defined as

```
    public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject, IProxy {
        public void DoStuff() {
            throw new DerivedException();
        }
    }
```

I have an Exception called DerivedException defined as

```
    [Serializable]
    public class DerivedException: ApplicationException {
        public DerivedException() : base () { }

        public DerivedException(string message) : base (message) { }
        public DerivedException(string message, Exception innerException) : base (message, innerException) { }
        protected DerivedException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
    }
```

When I call myProxy.DoStuff()

```
try{
    result = myProxy.DoStuff();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    myLog.Error("Error", ex);
}
```

I get an exception:

```
"Unable to find assembly 'xyz, Version=123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
...
```

I would think that my client code should be able to deserialize the thrown DerivedException since DerivedException inherits from Exception and the client code is set up to catch Exception. What am I doing wrong here? If I include the .dll that defines DerivedException in the bin/debug folder of the client code, the exception is received by the client properly. Is there any other way to get this exception to deserialize and be caught properly by the client code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be related to the fact that your `Proxy` derives from `MarshalByRefObject` and it that case an object reference is passed from one application domain to another, rather than the object itself.

On the other hand your `DerivedException` is marked as `Serializable`. When class is marked as `Serializable` it will automatically be serialized, transported from the one application domain to the other, and then deserialized to produce an exact copy of the object in the second application domain.

I would try mark `Proxy` class as `Serializable`. When this object is used with remoting, the formatter responsible for serialization, takes control of the serialization process, and replaces all objects derived from `MarshalByRefObject` with a proxy.

Comment: Thanks. This did not work however. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need the assembly where `DerivedException` is defined also on the client: the exception is thrown on the server, serialized and sent to the client. The client need to know what is that `DerivedException`.

A common way to handle it is to have a shared assembly installed both on client and on server, you can use the same assembly where you define `IProxy` for this

In opposite, the assembly where `Proxy` is defined is needed only in the server